# Difference between pyclean and py3clean

Tags: python, bytecode

Both `pyclean` and `py3clean` seem to have to same purpose:

**From pyclean [man page](https://unix.com/man-page/linux/1/pyclean)**: `pyclean - removes .pyc and .pyo files`

**From py3clean [man page](https://unix.com/man-page/linux/1/py3clean)**: `py3clean - removes .pyc and .pyo files`

The former doesn't seem to remove my `__pycache__` files however, while the latter works just fine.

Does anyone know why this might be the case, and what the difference is between these two programs?